# How to do while loops with multiple conditions

Tags: python, logic

I have a while loop in python

```
condition1=False
condition1=False
val = -1

while condition1==False and condition2==False and val==-1:
    val,something1,something2 = getstuff()

    if something1==10:
        condition1 = True

    if something2==20:
        condition2 = True

'
'
```

I want to break out of the loop when all these conditions are true, the code above does not work

I originally had

```
while True:
      if condition1==True and condition2==True and val!=-1:
         break
```

which works ok, is this the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "the code above does not work". What happens when you have the condition in the while statement?

Comment: Hi 

The first bit of code breaks out if any of the conditions are met, I want to break out when all the conditions are met 

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Change the `and`s to `or`s.

Comment: @SilentGhost: The condition given in the first blurb (which *maintains* the loop) is almost the negation of the condition given in the second blurb (which *breaks* the loop), except that it uses the wrong logical operator.

Answer (score 3):

```
while not condition1 or not condition2 or val == -1:
```

But there was nothing wrong with your original of using an if inside of a while True.

Answer (score 1):

Have you noticed that in the code you posted, `condition2` is never set to `False`? This way, your loop body is never executed.

Also, note that in Python, `not condition` is preferred to `condition == False`; likewise, `condition` is preferred to `condition == True`.

Answer (score 0):

```
condition1 = False
condition2 = False
val = -1
#here is the function getstuff is not defined, i hope you define it before
#calling it into while loop code

while condition1 and condition2 is False and val == -1:
#as you can see above , we can write that in a simplified syntax.
    val,something1,something2 = getstuff()

    if something1 == 10:
        condition1 = True

    elif something2 == 20:
# here you don't have to use "if" over and over, if have to then write "elif" instead    
    condition2 = True
# ihope it can be helpfull
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure it would read better but you could do the following:

```
while any((not condition1, not condition2, val == -1)):
    val,something1,something2 = getstuff()

    if something1==10:
        condition1 = True

    if something2==20:
        condition2 = True
```

Answer (score -2):

use an infinity loop like what you have originally done. Its cleanest and you can incorporate many conditions as you wish

```
while 1:
  if condition1 and condition2:
      break
  ...
  ...
  if condition3: break
  ...
  ...
```